# Setting options to label decorator using an INI file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

```
elements.elementName.options.decorators.label = "Label"
elements.elementName.options.decorators.label.options.tag = "div"
```

This used to work before upgrading from Zend 1.9.7 to 1.12.0. I can't find anywhere how it's supposed to work now. Without the second line it prints label, but without div tag. With the second line in place, it becomes very sad and says:

> `Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception`: Plugin by name 'Div' was not found in the registry

Comment: And which paths were used for the plugin loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah. Solved it myself. The answer was to change the first line to:

```
elements.elementName.options.decorators.label.decorator = "Label"
```

It just happened to work with older version even though the syntax was wrong.